# Timezone not working properly

Tags: android, timezone

I am getting date and time for India,Canada,USA.I am getting time and date correctly, 
But I am getting same timezone(GMT +5:30) for three countries. Actually I should get Different time zones Like for

```
 India  ------ Date IST.
 Canada ------ Date PST.
 USA    ------ Date PST.
```

Here is my logic

```
public void getDate(String timeZoneId) {
   String selectedId = timeZoneId;
    TimeZone timezone = TimeZone.getTimeZone(selectedId);
    TimeZoneName = timezone.getDisplayName();
    Log.v("TimeZoneName","TimeZoneName   "+TimeZoneName);
    int TimeZoneOffset = timezone.getRawOffset()
        / (60 * 1000);
    int hrs = TimeZoneOffset / 60;
    int mins = TimeZoneOffset % 60;
    miliSeconds = miliSeconds + timezone.getRawOffset();
    resultdate = new Date(miliSeconds);
    dateInCountry=sdf.format(resultdate);
    miliSeconds = 0;
}

private void getGMTTime() {
    current = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.ENGLISH);
     miliSeconds = current.getTimeInMillis();
     TimeZone tzCurrent = current.getTimeZone();
     int offset = tzCurrent.getRawOffset();
     if (tzCurrent.inDaylightTime(new Date())) {
         offset = offset + tzCurrent.getDSTSavings();
     }
     miliSeconds = miliSeconds - offset;
     resultdate = new Date(miliSeconds);
     System.out.println(sdf.format(resultdate));
}

 getGMTTime();
 getDate("Asia/Calcutta");
 final SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd yyyy hh:mm:ss a ");
 indTime.setText("Current Time " + String.valueOf(formatter.format(resultdate)) + TimeZoneName.substring(0,3));

 getGMTTime();
 getDate("Canada/Pacific");
 final SimpleDateFormat canadaFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd yyyy hh:mm:ss a ",Locale.CANADA);
 canadaTime.setText("Current Time " + String.valueOf(canadaFormatter.format(resultdate)) + TimeZoneName);
 canadaTime.setTypeface(titleType);

 getGMTTime();
 getDate("US/Pacific");
 final SimpleDateFormat usaFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd yyyy hh:mm:ss a ", Locale.US);
 usaTime.setText("Current Time " + String.valueOf(usaFormatter.format(resultdate)) + TimeZoneName);
```

I am getting date and time correctly but not the timezone

```
Ind     Mar 19 13:28:40 GMT+05:30 2016 

Canada  XXX XX XX:XX:XX GMT+05:30 2016

USA     XXX XX XX:XX:XX GMT+05:30 2016
```

Can you tell me Where I am wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems that your output does not correspond to the code that you showed. In the code, the formatters use 12-hours format, but the output is in 24-hour one. The output does not contain words "Current time ", the year is placed very strangely. It is unclear from the code where the last three four-line blocks are executed (no method for them). Could you show the exact code that you run and the given output?

Comment: Ok but my question was,how to get different time zone

Comment: How can we answer it without the real code and the real output?

Answer (score 0):

You can use in the following way to get the Timezone printed

final SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd yyyy hh:mm:ss **z** ");